# Detecting iOS app background termination by system

Tags: ios, background, terminate

What I'm trying to achieve is detecting when the system terminates an app while it is running in the background (not suspended). According to [this article](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1146930688654547/reducing-fooms-in-the-facebook-ios-app/) it can be done by process of elimination. One of the steps is deciding that user didn't force quit the app. I assume this is done by checking whether `applicationWillTerminate` was called. However, according to Apple's documentation this method can also be called by the system, so I'm not sure how it eliminates that option.

> For apps that do not support background execution or are linked
>   against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user
>   quits the app. For apps that support background execution, this method
>   is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app
>   simply moves to the background in that case. **However, this method may
>   be called in situations where the app is running in the background
>   (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.**

Is it possible to detect background system termination, and if so, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The [App Programming Guide for iOS: The App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW7) says:

> Suspended apps receive no notification when they are terminated; the system kills the process and reclaims the corresponding memory. If an app is currently running in the background and not suspended, the system calls the [`applicationWillTerminate:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) of its app delegate prior to termination. The system does not call this method when the device reboots.
>
> In addition to the system terminating your app, the user can terminate your app explicitly using the multitasking UI. User-initiated termination has the same effect as terminating a suspended app. The app’s process is killed and no notification is sent to the app.

The above is consistent with empirical tests.

In that [Reducing FOOMs in the Facebook iOS app](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1146930688654547/reducing-fooms-in-the-facebook-ios-app/) article, they mention the force quit situation where the app did "receive a termination call the last time the app was open": That only applies if the app was actively running and the user force quit it. But if the user first returns to the home screen (or otherwise suspends the app) and then force terminates the app, you will not receive that termination.

Bottom line, if the app is suspended at the time it was terminated, I do not believe that you have any reliable way of knowing whether it was jettisoned due to memory pressure or because the user force quit. The force quit scenario contemplated in that FOOM/BOOM article clearly only applies if the app was running when it was force quit.

Comment: What I'm trying to detect is a BOOM scenario. The problem is I can't differentiate between user terminating the app and system doing it while app is running (not suspended). From tests I've performed I saw that if app is running (foreground or background) `applicationWillTerminate:` is called whenever user terminates it using the multitasking UI. So if the app is terminated by the system while running it won't get called, even though the documentation says otherwise?

Comment: “if the app is terminated by the system while running it won't get called, even though the documentation says otherwise” ... If the OS needs to terminate your app running in the background because the OS is trying to free resources for some other active app, then you’ll see the normal lifecycle app delegate calls as the OS gracefully terminates your app. But if your app, itself, crashes because its own memory requests cannot be satisfied due to catestrophic failure to retrieve memory, it will be summarily killed and lifecycle events will not occur.